# How to pass arguments to a function through << operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload `<<` operator such that this works?

```
void f (int f)
{
}

int main ()
{
    f << 2;
}
```

What do I need to study for this to work?

Comment: What's it supposed to do?

Comment: @JamesKanze I intend to make f accessible through different classes in a simple way like cout << "dfdf";

Comment: But how is `f << 2` simpler than `f(2)`? It's confusing. Only overload operators if the resulting syntax is easy to read!

Comment: Which doesn't answer the question: what is it supposed to do.  `f` is accessible everywhere, as is; you don't need to do anything special.  `std::cout << "..."` doesn't just `std::cout` accessible; it has specific, defined behavior (which only makes sense if `std::cout` has state, i.e. is a class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f` needs to be an instance of a class with overloaded `operator <<`, or it must return an object of a type with the overloaded operator (but you'd need to call it `f()`).

```
struct F
{
   F& operator << (int x) { return *this; }
};

//...
F f;
f << 2;
```

Comment: AH, so I have to make a class which has a function which overloads << and then I have to create an object of that clasS?

Comment: Technically, `f` could also be an enum constant, with `<<` overloaded on the enum type..  I can't think of any case where this would be useful, but since I haven't the foggiest notion of what he's trying to accomplish...

Comment: @JamesKanze I am she. See my comment above. I thought using << will look simpler to the end user like cout <<.

Comment: @AnishaKaul Look simpler than what?  What is the desired behavior?  In C++, `<<` has two very different "pre-defined" behaviors: formatting and shifting.  In both cases, the behavior supposed that the left hand operand has state.  Unless you're formatting or shifting left, overloading `<<` is operator overload abuse, creating confusion in the user.

Comment: @AnishaKaul If the end user knows at least anything about C++, they will understand the function call syntax, but be *really* confused by the `<<` syntax. Unless you want to hide the fact that you're calling a function.

Comment: @JamesKanze It is clear now. I did not know better, please put that last comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make any call like

```
f << arg1 << ... << argN;
```

to behave the same as

```
f(arg1, ..., argN);
```

then the follwing **C++11** code does what you want.

For every function you want to call like this, create a "proxy object" holding the arguments to be called on the function `f`. This object should return a new "proxy object" which then requires one argument less. Nice side-effect: this can be used for argument currying.

Here is the full code with a running example: http://ideone.com/NFtnuT

In a nutshell, this code does the following: It defines a template class with variadic template arguments:

```
template<class R, /* ... */>
class ProxyFunction
{
    // Underlying function:
    std::function<R(/* ... */)> f;

public:
    ProxyFunction(std::function<R(/* ... */)> f) : f(f) {}

    ProxyFunction<R, /* one arg less */> operator <<(/* one argument */) {
         /* create new proxy function with one argument less */
    }
};
```

For the last argument, you should call the underlying function on either destruction or when casting to the return type `R`. This is done by partially specializing the template class for the case where `/*...*/` actually is *nothing*.

The code is then called as:

```
// Create proxy function. You can pass f around as you want.
auto f = makeProxy(/* underlying "real" function */);

// Call f using this syntax, discarding the result:
f << a << b;

// Use its result:
int result = f << a << b;
```

Now the nice thing about this is that it supports **currying**:

```
auto g = (f << a);      // Bind first parameter, but don't call yet.
int result = (g << b);  // Bind second parameter, now call it.
```

Comment: How about defining `operator<<` as a free function and giving the proxy class the same constructors as `std::function`, so that you don't need to `makeProxy`?

Answer (score 2):

Overloading an operator is only legal if at least one of the
operands has a user defined *type* (class type or enum).  You
could conceivably define something like:

```
?? operator<<( void (*f)( int ), MyType );
```

where `MyType` is either an enum or a class type (but not an
`int`), but do you want to?  In C++, `<<` has two established
meanings: formatting data (for eventual output), and left shift
(both of which imply state in the left hand operand).
Overloading the operator to do something unrelated is operating
overload abuse.  When the reader sees a `<<`, he has a right to
assume that some sort of formatting or shifting is going on.
Overloading `<<` for something unrelated will confuse him.